# How can i put my destop application online

Tags: vb.net, web-applications

I am writing codes on Vb.Net. I am curious about if i write my desktop on VB.Net then is it possible to convert it as a web application.

To be more specific: I am writing a CRM software on VB with Crystal Reports. But i want to carry my desktop app to my web site.

Comment: You probably don't want a Desktop app. More likely a Service that produces reports.

Comment: Web apps and desktop apps are very different platforms and is not a simple task to jump from one to the other.  However with a good solution design you can separate your UI from Business logic and Data access meaning front end for the application can be comparatively interchangeable